# Easymock mocking inputstream read operation

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I want to test following code with easymock. I have created mock socket and mock inputstream but I am not able to mock the read method. Can anyone please help me

```
byte[] lenbuf = new byte[2];
sock.getInputStream().read(lenbuf);
```

I am trying following in my unit test

```
InputStream mockInputStream = createMock(InputStream.class);
expect(mockInputStream.read(new byte[2])).andReturn(2);
replay(mockInputStream);
```

it gives me following error

```
  Unexpected method call InputStream.read([0, 0]):
  InputStream.read([0, 0]): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a matcher. Either `EasyMock.aryEq()` or `EasyMock.capture()` depending on how you want to test it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Aside: try `(byte[]) EasyMock.anyObject()` instead of `new byte[2]` as the parameter to read.)*

Mocking an input stream is a lot of work and not really worth doing.  There are many ways to get fake input streams that your tests can set up, without using mock objects.  Try this:

```
String fakeInput = "This is the string that your fake input stream will return";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(fakeInput);
InputStream fakeStream = new ReaderInputStream(reader);
```

Note that ReaderInputStream is in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html)

You can also do it without the Reader, using StringBufferInputStream.  This doesn't require Commons IO.  It has deficiencies, but it's probably good enough for test code.

In fact, mocking in general is hard work compared to other forms of faking.  I do it only when I want to prove that the that innards of my class being tested is doing something in a particular way, and that's not really what tests are for: good tests prove the interfaces work, and allow the implementations to change.  Have a read of the eminent Martin Fowler's [definition of mocks](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) and Andrew Trenk's take on [some of the problems they can introduce](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.nz/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html).

Comment: +1 for your stubbing advice. Followed that and it made my test simple :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same object in the target class and unit test when using EasyMock#expect.
In the target class's `new byte[2]` and unit test's `new byte[2]` is different object.
You might want to pass the object through argument or interface.

Example:

```
// Unit test
@Test
public targetMethodTest() {
    InputStream mockInputStream = createMock(InputStream.class);
    byte[] lenbuf = new byte[2];
    expect(mockInputStream.read(lenbuf)).andReturn(2);
    replay(mockInputStream);
    ...
    targetClass.targetMethod(lenbuf);
}
```

...

```
// target method in target class
public void targetMethod(byte[] lenbuf) {
    ...
    sock.getInputStream().read(lenbuf);
}
```

If you don't care about the value of `lenbuf`, you can use `anyObject()` instead of `new byte[2]`.

```
expect(mockInputStream.read(anyObject())).andReturn(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputStream mockInputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream("fake string", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```